# problem generating python plots

Tags: python, elpy, ein

I am very new to emacs and I can't figure out why my plots doesn't appear, I have `ein` and `elpy` installed, my code runs but I just can't see the plot. I installed the packages in `M-x list-packages`.

My .emacs looks like this :

```
;(setq debug-on-error t)

;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-archives
   (quote
    (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (org ein elpy flycheck py-autopep8 material-theme))))

(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))

(setq inhibit-startup-message t) ;; hide the startup message
(load-theme 'material t) ;; load material theme
(global-linum-mode t) ;; enable line numbers globally


(elpy-enable)
(elpy-use-ipython)
(require 'ein)

;; use flycheck not flymake with elpy
(when (require 'flycheck nil t)
  (setq elpy-modules (delq 'elpy-module-flymake elpy-modules))
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode))

;; enable autopep8 formatting on save
(require 'py-autopep8)
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)


(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

A code snippet :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
plt.plot(a,b)
```

Result :

```
In [7]: Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x110a80c50>]
```

How can I make the plot show up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an emacs problem as far as I can see.

To let a plot show up in python (using matplotlib) use:

`plt.show()`

Comment: I'm sorry for using the main answer to write this little thing, but my reputation is still now high enough to comment your question. Somehow I have to increase it.

Comment: That's kind embarrassing actually, but worked, I think that I was overly accustomed with and IDE that did all the tricks for me.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm glad it worked. Sometimes the issues are in the simplest things... Thank you for feedback!

Comment: after I run plt.show(), this ipython buffer will be dead, can you help?